# Fast CGI, Lighttpd, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lighttpd, fastcgi

Is this log file familiar to someone of UBUNTU users?

Lighttpd log file:

```
> 2009-08-30 21:37:45: (log.c.75) server started 
> 2009-08-30 21:37:45: (mod_fastcgi.c.1029) the fastcgi-backend php5-cgi *failed* to start: 
> 2009-08-30 21:37:45: (mod_fastcgi.c.1033) *child exited with status 9 php5-cgi* 
> 2009-08-30 21:37:45: (mod_fastcgi.c.1036) If you're trying to run PHP as a FastCGI backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.
> You can find out if it is the right one by executing 'php -v' and it should display '(cgi-fcgi)' in the output, NOT '(cgi)' NOR '(cli)'.
> For more information, check http://trac.lighttpd.net/trac/wiki/Docs%3AModFastCGI#preparing-php-as-a-fastcgi-programIf this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags. 
> 2009-08-30 21:37:45: (mod_fastcgi.c.1340) [ERROR]: *spawning fcgi failed*. 
> 2009-08-30 21:37:45: (server.c.908) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.
```

Please open a secret how did you solved fcgi problem and made lighttpd to start, if you did.

Thx, Gosh.

Answer (score 1):

Find correct path to PHP executable. You might need to use `php-cgi` version (the default `php` might be `php-cli`, which is not suitable).

If you don't have one, install php-cgi package or compile PHP with `--enable-fcgi`.